# How can make a plot with 2 lines to let one line start from value n from X axis in python?

Tags: python

I have two numpy array data: sales_test and prediction. Array “sales_test" shape is (86,), the value is array([ 420258,  364900,  309364,  ...], dtype=int64). Array "prediction" shape is (56,), the value is array([ 7.92954980e+03,  7.60529297e+03,  1.98806812e+03,  7.97242480e+03,
        8.26193848e+03,  ....],dtype=float32).
Now I plot these two data into one picture, my code is:

```
plt.plot(prediction, label='predict')
plt.plot(sales_test,label='actual', alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And it shows like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz4zZ.png)

The "predict" line starts from the beginning point 0, but I want it starts from 30. So that two lines have the same end point on X axis. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround.

```
prediction = np.array([0.0] * 30 + list(prediction))

plt.plot(prediction, label='predict')
plt.plot(sales_test,label='actual', alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```